# DELETE FROM INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando eliminar unas lineas de traduccion de un lenguage especifico. No puedo eliminar todo el `language_id  9` de la tabla porque eliminaria las lineas de todo, entonces necesito irme a la tabla anterior para ver la relacion con la tabla padre, pero resulta que tengo un error en la siguiente sentencia sql.

```sql
DELETE FROM creative_from_subject_lines_rel_langs t1 
INNER JOIN creative_from_subject_lines t2 ON t2.id = t1.creative_from_subject_lines_id 
WHERE t1.vertical_id = '1' 
AND t2.language_id = '9';
```

Pero me sale este error .

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'INNER JOIN creative_from_subject_lines ON creative_from_subject_lines.id = cr...'
> en la linea 1

Que creen que puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 2):

Falta a indicar la tabla a borrar, que es necesario cuando utilizas un `JOIN` en un `DELETE`, de lo contrario ¿Como sabría cual dato borrar?

```
--      v--ESTO 
DELETE t1 FROM creative_from_subject_lines_rel_langs t1 
INNER JOIN creative_from_subject_lines t2 ON t2.id = t1.creative_from_subject_lines_id 
WHERE t1.vertical_id = '1' 
AND t2.language_id = '9';
```

El caso anterior es si quieres borrar solo los registros de `t1`, para `t2`

```
DELETE t2 FROM creative_from_subject_lines_rel_langs t1 
--ETC
```

Y para borrar los registros en ambas tablas

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM creative_from_subject_lines_rel_langs t1 
--ETC
```